# If I send data by bluetooth low energy, can I know the status of transferring?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to learn more about by this [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple.

This sample can send text from an iOS device to another one.

There is a method called:

> -(BOOL)updateValue:(NSData *)value forCharacteristic:(CBMutableCharacteristic *)characteristic onSubscribedCentrals:(NSArray *)centrals;

When this sample send text by this method, it will return a BOOL to let you know succes or not.

It's easy and clear.

But I have doubt about :

Is this provide by BLE?

Or it's because of CoreBluetooth API?

In other words , If I receive data from other BLE device(not iOS device).

Could that device know that I've received data?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your questions? It's not clear what kind of answer you're expecting on what.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. If I have a development kit like CC2540. When this development kit send data to an iOS device by ble. I hope when the data transfer failed , the development kit would make some alarms to notified. My question is, is this a standars protocol in ble gatt, or it has to be defined by TI?

Comment: For other visitors:
Here is the same post solved: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/180834?tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

In BLE, when your central device (here iOS device, assumed to be master, and also the client) wants to send data to a peripheral device (assumed to be slave and the server), it has several options to do it:

(1) write to a characteristic value

(2) write command to a characteristic value

The difference is (1) has a response from the peripheral device. (2) doesn't have that. The advantage of (2) over (1) is that (2) can send multiple data blindly while (1) has to wait until there is a response to previous write before it could send next data.

Similarly, if your peripheral device (as server) wants to send some data to your iOS device, you could either indicate (with acknowledgement) or notify (without ack).

Hope this helps.